# opening Array in ruby on rails console v. irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wish to make my code a little more readable by calling #rando on any array and retrieve a random element (rando because a rand() method already exists and I don't want there to be *any* confusion).

So I opened up the class and wrote a method:

```
class Array
    def rando
       self[ rand(length) ]
    end
end
```

This seems far too straightforward.

When I open up irb, and type `arr = %w(hi bye)` and then `arr.rando` I get either hi or bye back. That's expected. However, in my rails console, when I do the same thing, I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

I've been tracing `Array` up the rails chain and can't figure it out. Any idea?

FWIW, I'm using rails 2.3.11 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: By the way, Ruby offers such a method. Unfortunately, it's called differently in 1.8 and 1.9. In 1.8, you can use `Array#choice`, in 1.9 it's `Array#sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in my case :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > class Array
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002?>       def rando
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003?>            self[ rand(length) ]
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004?>         end
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006 > arr = %w(hi bye)
 => ["hi", "bye"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > arr.rando
 => "bye"
```